# How to run Hive job on subset of nodes

Tags: hadoop, hive, solid-state-drive

We have 100+ node hadoop cluster. In this few nodes 20+ have SSD as backend store. We want to run Hive job/query on these 20+ nodes that have SSD and measure the performance. In this context is it possible to specify the nodes on which the hive job/query should run + nodes where the data associated with this should be stores (i.e. data stored and computed/processed on some pre-specified set of nodes)

Comment: YARN node labels will control which NodeManagers get used, but that doesn't guarantee data locality against HDFS

Comment: You mean processing on specific nodes is possible but ensuring data locality is not?

Comment: Right. Which usually isn't a big deal within a local networking

Comment: Right. If possible can you give an example (link) on how to achieve this?

Comment: If you'd search it, you get the official documentation. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html